# How do you make a circle from origin

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am trying to draw a target like this: [image: like this]
<sub>(source: [newscientist.com](https://www.newscientist.com/blogs/culturelab/target_1.jpg))</sub>

using turtle.

The problem is turtle includes the origin as part of the graph, as opposed to the origin being in the center. My question is, how do I get turtle draw a circle AROUND the origin rather than include it?

```
import turtle

radius = 100
turtle.speed(0)

for rings in range(10):


    turtle.circle(radius)
    radius += 10
```

Comment: as you can see, all these circles have a common center. That would tend to indicate that the origin of the drawing is at the center rather than outside of it.

Comment: Right, but the origin is included as a point in the drawing. Run the code and you will see what I mean

Comment: I have never used turtle, but why `origin is included as a point in the drawing` is a bad thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import turtle

radius = 100
turtle.speed(0)

for rings in range(10):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(0, -radius)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(radius)
    radius += 10
```

Answer (score 2):

It's nicer to use radius as the loop variable

```
import turtle

turtle.speed(0)

for radius in range(100, 200, 10):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(0, -radius)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(radius)
```

Then you might wish to define a function

```
import turtle

turtle.speed(0)

def origin_circle(turtle, radius):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(0, -radius)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(radius)

for radius in range(100, 200, 10):
    origin_circle(turtle, radius)
```

Comment: What is range(100, 200, 10) for?